# Conversion between std::tuple and boost::tuple

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, variadic-templates, c++14

Given a `boost::tuple` and `std::tuple`, how do you convert between them?

In other words, how would you implement the following two functions?

```
template <typename... T> boost::tuple<T...> asBoostTuple(  std::tuple<T...> stdTuple);
template <typename... T>   std::tuple<T...> asStdTuple  (boost::tuple<T...> boostTuple);
```

Seems to be a straightforward thing, but I could not find any good solutions.

---

*What did I try?*

I ended up solving it with template programming. It seems to work in my concrete setup, but it does not feel right (too verbose), and I'm even not sure if it actually works in all situations (I'll come to that point later).

Anyway, here is the interesting part:

```
template<int offset, typename... T>
struct CopyStdTupleHelper
{
    static void copy(boost::tuple<T...> source, std::tuple<T...>& target) {
        std::get<offset>(target) = std::move(boost::get<offset>(source));
        CopyStdTupleHelper<offset - 1, T...>::copy(source, target);
    }

    static void copy(std::tuple<T...> source, boost::tuple<T...>& target) {
        boost::get<offset>(target) = std::move(std::get<offset>(source));
        CopyStdTupleHelper<offset - 1, T...>::copy(source, target);
    }
};

template<typename... T>
struct CopyStdTupleHelper<-1, T...>
{
    static void copy(boost::tuple<T...> source, std::tuple<T...>& target)
      { /* nothing to do (end of recursion) */ }

    static void copy(std::tuple<T...> source, boost::tuple<T...>& target)
      { /* nothing to do (end of recursion) */ }
};


std::tuple<T...> asStdTuple(boost::tuple<T...> boostTuple) {
    std::tuple<T...> result;
    CopyStdTupleHelper<sizeof...(T) - 1, T...>::copy(std::move(boostTuple), result);
    return result;
}

boost::tuple<T...> asBoostTuple(std::tuple<T...> stdTuple) {
    boost::tuple<T...> result;
    CopyStdTupleHelper<sizeof...(T) - 1, T...>::copy(std::move(stdTuple), result);
    return result;
}
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way. It seems like a very common operation to wrap existing APIs using `boost::tuple` to `std::tuple`.

---

I tried to provide you with a minimal test example, where only the implementation of `asBoostTuple` and `asStdTuple` is missing. However, for some magic with `boost::tuples::null_type`, which I don't fully understand, it fails to compile. That is also the reason why I'm not sure that my existing solution can be generally applied.

Here is the snippet:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

template <typename... T>
boost::tuple<T...> asBoostTuple(std::tuple<T...> stdTuple) {
  boost::tuple<T...> result;
  // TODO: ...
  return result;
}

template <typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> asStdTuple(boost::tuple<T...> boostTuple) {
  std::tuple<T...> result;
  // TODO: ...
  return result;
}

int main() {
  boost::tuple<std::string, int, char> x = asBoostTuple(std::make_tuple("A", 1, 'x'));

  // ERROR: 
  std::tuple<std::string, int, char> y = asStdTuple<std::string, int, char>(x);

  return x == y;
}
```

The error message is:

```
example.cpp:20:38: error: no viable conversion from 'tuple<[3 *
      ...], boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
      boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
      boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
      boost::tuples::null_type>' to 'tuple<[3 * ...], (no
      argument), (no argument), (no argument), (no argument),
      (no argument), (no argument), (no argument)>'
  ...int, char> y = asStdTuple<std::string, int, char>(x);
```

I understand that Boost's implementation is not based on variadic templates, which should explain the `null_type`, but still I'm not sure how to avoid that compile error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual trick when doing this sort of manipulations is to construct an integer sequence and then use a pack expansion to initialize the new tuple.

The extra twist in this case is `null_type`. For that it's probably simplest to treat the tuple type as opaque, and manipulate it using `boost::tuples::length` and `boost::tuples::element`, which already handles `null_type` properly. This way you do not rely on the implementation details of boost tuples.

So:

```
template <typename StdTuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto asBoostTuple(StdTuple&& stdTuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return boost::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::decay_t<StdTuple>>...>
                        (std::get<Is>(std::forward<StdTuple>(stdTuple))...);
}

template <typename BoostTuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto asStdTuple(BoostTuple&& boostTuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::tuple<typename boost::tuples::element<Is, std::decay_t<BoostTuple>>::type...>
                     (boost::get<Is>(std::forward<BoostTuple>(boostTuple))...);
}

template <typename StdTuple>
auto asBoostTuple(StdTuple&& stdTuple) {
  return asBoostTuple(std::forward<StdTuple>(stdTuple),
             std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<StdTuple>>::value>());
}

template <typename BoostTuple>
auto asStdTuple(BoostTuple&& boostTuple) {
  return asStdTuple(std::forward<BoostTuple>(boostTuple),
             std::make_index_sequence<boost::tuples::length<std::decay_t<BoostTuple>>::value>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03e9fc14aafc9d17).

Note that the basic structure of the code is exactly identical for the two situations: we obtain the size of the tuple (via `boost::tuples::length` or `std::tuple_size`), construct an integer sequence using `std::make_index_sequence`, and then use the integer sequence to obtain the types with `boost::tuples::element` and `std::tuple_element`, and the values with `boost::get`/`std::get`.